# In Haskell, how to flush Data.Text every line?

Tags: haskell, text

How can I change this program to immediately process every line of text in case of interactive input? Preferably flush buffer every newline character.

```
main = do
  input <- T.getContents
  mapM_ T.putStrLn $ T.lines input
```

Update: Something is still missing. Take a look (`????` is after newline, stdout is printed out after reaching `EOF` on stdin) :

```
> cat Test.hs
import System.IO
import Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.IO as T

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
    input <- T.getContents
    mapM_ T.putStrLn $ T.lines input
> runhaskell Test.hs
a
????
a
????
> runhaskell --version
runghc 7.6.3
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to use lazy input to interleave reading lines and handling them.

`getContents` from `Data.Text.IO` is *not* lazy, and will read everything before returning anything at all.

Import the version from `Data.Text.Lazy.IO` instead.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use `hSetBuffering` from `System.IO`:

```
import System.IO

main = do
    hSetBuffering stdout LineBuffering
    input <- T.getContents
    mapM_ T.putStrLn $ T.lines input
```